# What material can I put on my wood kitchen island to make the surface smooth and waterproof?

Tags: woodworking, wooden-furniture, wood-finishing, epoxy

We have this relatively low cost high top dining table that we've turned into our kitchen island. It's been working out great so far but the tables surface is ridged and has a lot of divots that don't all go in the same direction so it makes wiping it down a bit of a pain. Also, the constant wiping is starting to cause some of the finish to chip away.

I was wondering if there is an low cost clear epoxy type material that I can paint onto it that would make the surface smooth and water resistant?

[image]
[image]

Comment: YouTube is full of "how to epoxy a table" videos. Epoxy may not fall into the "low cost" catagory

Answer (score 3):

Alaska Man's epoxy suggestion is what came to mind for me as well, but it might be difficult to get a nice edge without a lip of some sort. I admit that I've never worked with the stuff.

I think I'd be ordering **a sheet of 1/4" glass** with a pencil edge. It would probably look great and wouldn't cost much. Wouldn't have to be tempered if you're careful folks with dishes that aren't too heavy. I've used such on my desk since childhood without issue.

It might help to wipe the surface with a wood stain or color in the worn streaks with a colored marker before you set the glass down.

Comment: yea the glass option isnt a bad one. I guess I was hoping there was a low cost version of epoxy. thanks for the response!